# Custom User Control with Listbox data binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, listbox, user-controls, custom-controls

Can not get my custom user control to bind items to my list box from outside of the control itself.

SystemUpdateControl.cs:

```
public partial class SystemUpdateControl : UserControl
{
    private BindingList<string> test = new BindingList<string>();

    private ListBox lb = new ListBox();

    public BindingList<string> tp
    {
        get { return test; }
        set
        {
            if (value == test)
                return;
            test = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public SystemUpdateControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Width = 120;
        this.Height = 120;

        lb = new ListBox()
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            Left = 10,
            Top = 10
        };
        this.Controls.Add(lb);
        lb.DataSource = test;
    }
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(addValue);
    }
    private void addValue()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        string[] tst = new string[] { "TEST", "TEST2" };
        foreach( string s in tst)
        {
            systemUpdateControl1.tp.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I will be adding more items to the user control, I just want to get this part working before I go any further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why use `UserControl`, instead of inheriting from `ListBox`?

Comment: Because I will have a listbox, 2 buttons, labels, and a text box. The list box will need values sent to it as well as the text box and labels.